# axios couple of `.then` promises - how to combine them?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

Let say I have a wrapper for `axios` function - something that should be implemented on every ajax query so I want to keep code DRY. Like that:

```
import axios     from "axios"
import NProgress from "nprogress"

const query = (url, options) => {
  NProgress.start()

  return axios({
    url: url,
    method: options.method || "GET",
    data: options.data || {}
  }).then(() => {
    NProgress.done()
  })
}

export default query
```

The problem is that if I'm adding `.then` resolver to `query()`, nothing is happened! Like that:

import query from "./query.js"

```
query("something", {}).then(() => { console.log("This will never logged") })
```

How can I add another `.then()` to `query()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return something!

```
const query = (url, options) => {
  NProgress.start()

  return axios({
    url: url,
    method: options.method || "GET",
    data: options.data || {}
  }).then((response) => {
    NProgress.done()
    return response // change is here
  })
}
```